# Generalized Additive Model Python Libraries

Tags: python, generalized-additive-model

I know that R has gam and mgcv libraries for generalized additive models.  But I am having difficulty finding their counterparts in the Python ecosystem (statsmodels only has prototype in the sandbox).  Is anyone aware of existing python libraries?  Who knows this might be a good project to develop/contribute to scikit-learn if not.

Comment: statsmodels had a GSOC project for GAM and penalized splines https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/2744

Comment: @user333700 Interesting.  Is this distinct from the scikit-learn GSOC '15 project described here? : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/wiki/Google-summer-of-code-(GSOC)-2015

Comment: It's completely independent of scikit-learn. In the first round, as in the PR, only GLM will be supported. scikit-learn didn't have a GSOC project for it, AFAIK.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've written a Python implementation of GAMs using penalized B-splines.

check it out here: https://github.com/dswah/pyGAM

I've included lots of link functions, distributions and features.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for quick experimentation with GAM models is the package https://github.com/malmgrek/gammy.

The emphasis is on Bayesian modeling of the GAM coefficients as well as easy extensibility on custom basis functions. Currently e.g. Gaussian processes, B-splines, as well as different trivial constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Another recent development are neural additive models which apply the GAM approach to a deep learning architecture:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.13912

https://github.com/nickfrosst/neural_additive_models